# How to put row colors of a seaborn clustermap in the right side?

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, hierarchical-clustering

I have been trying to generate a clustermap with col and row colors as the one below, but I am not able to put the row colors in the right side of the plot, between the heatmap and the y-axis labels (similarly to the col colors, that are in the top between the heatmap and x-axis dendrogram).

[Clustermap that I am generating with col and row colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHITQ.png)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of the code you have attempted